# jwplayer js api event get index of player

Tags: javascript, events, video, jwplayer

I'm facing with the jwplayer api and I want to get some events, but I will have more than one player in my page, so when I get an event, I need to know which player is firing the event.

Something like the youtube api does:

```
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
       n = event.target.id - 1; //The index of the player which fire the event
    }
```

But in jwplayer I don't know how to do:

```
//PARA TODOS LOS REPRODUCTORES
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
   var id = videos[i];
   jwplayer(id).setup({
        file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/lWMJeVvV-364767.mp4",
        events: {
            onReady: function(ev) { 
                    alert('ha iniciado el reproductor '+INDEX OF THE PLAYER WHICH FIRE THE EVENT);
            },
            onComplete: function(ev) {
                alert('ha finalizando el reproductor '+INDEX OF THE PLAYER WHICH FIRE THE EVENT);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save whatever you want this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
   var id = videos[i];
   jwplayer(id).setup({
        file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/lWMJeVvV-364767.mp4",
        my_var: videos[i], /*WHATEVER YOU WANT AS A VARIABLE OF THE PLAYER*/
        events: {
            onReady: function(ev) { 
                    alert('ha iniciado el reproductor '+this.config.my_var);
            },
            onComplete: function(ev) {
                alert('ha finalizando el reproductor '+this.config.my_var);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using our API - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

You can target specific players.

For example, jwplayer() will be the first player on a page, but you can also do jwplayer('my-player'), to target a player called 'my-player', for example. You don't need to set the events in the events block either, you can set them up in outside scripts.